# Trading View Widget it shows me errors

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

I have a problem with Trading View because it shows some errors in Console Log and Widget it works, but the errors still show on Consone Log and I am not able to fix this?

````
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Website Name</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-tickers.js">
                                {
                  "symbols"; [
                    {
                      "title": "EUR/USD",
                      "proName": "FX_IDC:EURUSD"
                    },
                    {
                      "description": "GBP/USD",
                      "proName": "OANDA:GBPUSD"
                    },
                    {
                      "description": "GBP/JPY",
                      "proName": "OANDA:GBPJPY"
                    },
                    {
                      "description": "EUR/GBP",
                      "proName": "OANDA:EURGBP"
                    },
                    {
                      "description": "EUR/JPY",
                      "proName": "OANDA:EURJPY"
                    }
                  ],
                  "colorTheme"; "dark",
                  "isTransparent"; false,
                  "locale"; "en"
                }
                    </script>
    </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a library you should first call it, and then use it. 
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-tickers.js"></script>
<script>
{
  "symbols"; [
  {
    "title": "EUR/USD",
    "proName": "FX_IDC:EURUSD"
   },
   {
     "description": "GBP/USD",
     "proName": "OANDA:GBPUSD"
   },
   {
     "description": "GBP/JPY",
     "proName": "OANDA:GBPJPY"
   },
   {
     "description": "EUR/GBP",
     "proName": "OANDA:EURGBP"
    },
    {
      "description": "EUR/JPY",
      "proName": "OANDA:EURJPY"
    }
  ],
  "colorTheme"; "dark",
  "isTransparent"; false,
  "locale"; "en"
}
</script>
```

Comment: It shows me the errors still on Console Log http://prntscr.com/ofx0r6
And here's Codepen so you could try and see the full error 
https://codepen.io/beh4r/pen/gNVdRL

Comment: OK. The errors are from the widget and not something wrong with your code. You know it since it point to the file that you embed.

Comment: Any idea if you could help me validate this code with JSON because when I checked this code on JSON validator it showed me I need 4-5 errors fixed?
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I fond couple of demos here: https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/ that all share errors on console. In all the code is first calling (embed) the script and then modify it with another script. This is how libraries work.

Comment: I see and looks like I have to use with these errors and my concern is with security that if I leave the errors still would be any change to get hacked?

Comment: Can't guarantee that since the source is not something on your responsibility... I played with it myself and it's working despite the errors. whether use it or not is something you should decide (:

Answer (score 0):

simply replace the ';' by ':'.